# How to dynamically construct json in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I would like to construct a dynamic json and do a post call. I am using ${data.list.name} to get the value from an object but it is not working. Is there a way to do this?

```
function callTeams (data) {
  fetch(WEBHOOK, {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    'body': JSON.stringify({
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "0076D7",
    "sections": [{
        "activityTitle": "${data.list.name} is valid",
        "activityImage": "https://teamsnodesample.azurewebsites.net/static/img/image5.png",
        "facts": [  {
            "name": "Key",
            "value": "${data.list.name}"
        }],
        "markdown": true
    }],
    "potentialAction": [ {
        "@type": "OpenUri",
        "name": "Submit",
        "targets": [{
            "os": "default",
            "uri": "https://learn.microsoft.com/outlook/actionable-messages"
        }]
    }]
})
  })
}
```

Comment: use basic string concatenation or [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: why you wrapping `name` with `"${...}"`? Past value directly if it is string or use `\`\``

Comment: I tried with both double quote and single quote but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Replace things like

```
{
   "activityTitle": "${data.list.name} is valid"
}
```

with

```
{
   "activityTitle": `${data.list.name} is valid`
}
```

In other words, use backticks (`)

Comment: Thanks for your response. tried with both double quote and single quote but it is not working. I got response like $ is valid.

Comment: It's neither double quote or single quote, it's the ` character

Comment: ohh yeah. it worked with ` character. Thanks